ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series in pandas DataFrame

python: 3.11
pandas: 2.2.2

I need to assign a dict value to 4-th row in df:
df = pd.DataFrame({'agg': [None] * 5})
df['agg'] = df['agg'].astype(object)
df.loc[3, 'agg'] = {'mm': 4}

It gives an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sirjay/python/ethereum/lib/analyse_30m.py", line 1898, in <module>
    df.loc[3, 'agg'] = {'mm': 4}
    ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sirjay/miniconda3/envs/eth/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 911, in __setitem__
    iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
  File "/home/sirjay/miniconda3/envs/eth/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1944, in _setitem_with_indexer
    self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)
  File "/home/sirjay/miniconda3/envs/eth/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2189, in _setitem_single_block
    value = self._align_series(indexer, Series(value))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/sirjay/miniconda3/envs/eth/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2455, in _align_series
    raise ValueError("Incompatible indexer with Series")
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series

How to fix? This option df['agg'].loc[3] = {'mm': 4} works, but with warning:
Use `df.loc[row_indexer, "col"] = values` instead, to perform the assignment in a single step and ensure this keeps updating the original `df`.

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy


You can use df.at:
df.at[3, 'agg'] = {'mm': 4}

Output:
         agg
0       None
1       None
2       None
3  {'mm': 4}
4       None

Alternatively, use boolean indexing, as suggested in this post:
m = df.index == 2
df.loc[m, 'agg'] = [{'mm': 3}] * m.sum()

Output:
         agg
0       None
1       None
2  {'mm': 3} # <- added
3  {'mm': 4}
4       None

